# tweepy (tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized)

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I want to retrieve tweets using Twitter API of basic developer account. I do not have too much knowledge of using API for scraping. I already set my Authentication Token's permission to Read and Write as well as write a possible correct code for retrieving tweets. Can anybody help me with this? What should I do to allow myself to retrieve tweets from Twitter?

This is my current code (the keys and tokens were replaced as 'XXXX'):

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'XXXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXXX'
access_token = 'XXXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXXX'

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)

query = 'QUERY'
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Year 3 (Sem 1)\Investigation Report\Coding\Testing Scrape 5.py", line 17, in <module>
    tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Year 3 (Sem 1)\Investigation Report\Coding\venv\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 1266, in search_recent_tweets
    return self._make_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Year 3 (Sem 1)\Investigation Report\Coding\venv\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 129, in _make_request
    response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Year 3 (Sem 1)\Investigation Report\Coding\venv\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 98, in request
    raise Unauthorized(response)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should have been subscribed to basic plan of Twitter. Also use twitter V2 APIs use reference:

`https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/tree/main`.

I also fixed the issue by following github code in recent.

Also you can check postman collection:

`https://www.postman.com/twitter/workspace/twitter-s-public-workspace/`

Comment: Postman collection seems working for me. Thank you for your help @SantChanana

Comment: @GabrielLiew Currently I'm using free tier of twitter APIs. I'll move to basic subscription later, So I wanted to know while fetching tweets of Users does it asks for verify app ?
Because while using free tier  API i.e. to add tweet It asks for verify APP. So is it happening with tweets fetching API also ?

Comment: Hi @SantChanana, have you tried to enter your bearer token in the Postman's Authorization? I tried fetching tweets from query or multiple tweets and I didn't encounter the issue you mentioned.

Comment: Actually right now I don't have basic subscription, thats why this API won't work for me for now. I was just confirming that bearer token received from twitter API key section will work for fetching multiple tweets API ?

Comment: Yes, with bearer token and basic subscription, you are able to fetch multiple tweets